# "[Brand] Terms and Privacy" vs. "the [Brand] Terms and Privacy"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, zero-article

I just developed a sign-up form for my website, but as English is not my native language I'm not sure which wording of the following sentence is correct:

> - I agree to [Brand name] Terms and Privacy.
> - I agree to the [Brand name] Terms and Privacy.

I've searched on several big websites, but I've come across both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the brand name to be Mysite, you could use either of these:

*I agree to Mysite's Terms and Privacy.*

*I agree to the Mysite Terms and Privacy.*

But I would add "policy" to the end of the sentence: ..*Terms and Privacy Policy*.